# Saber dónde se está dando clic o tocando la pantalla en Unity 2d

Tags: unity2d

Hola estoy haciendo un juego de flappy bird. Quiero que cuando el jugador toque la pantalla o de clic el pájaro "brinque". Esta parte ya la tengo hecha. El problema es que en mi pantalla también tengo un botón y cuando lo presiono ya sea dando clic o tocando la pantalla el juego interactúa con el botón (lo cual esta bien) pero también hace que el pájaro brinque lo cual no quiero. ¿Qué hago para que cuando presione el botón sólo interactúe con el botón pero cuando presione cualquier otra parte de la pantalla (que es lo que me interesa) el pájaro brinque?

Aquí les muestro un método que retorna verdadero si el jugador ha dado clic o tocado la pantalla, me interesa que se ejecute sólo cuando doy clic en la pantalla y no cuando doy clic en un botón:

```
void Update(){   
    Up();
}

void Up(){
    if(DetectJump())
    {
        //El pájaro salta
    }
}

bool DetectJump(){
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) ||
        Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began ||
        Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
            return true;
        }
    else return false;
}
```

Espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: Te recomiendo que utilices el portal de Game Dev de Stackoverflow [GameDev] (https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabia que existía.